# Unlock the key-chain in mac through python

Tags: python, keychain

Is there any way to unlock the key-chain in mac through python. I got it in bash as `security unlock-keychain -p $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD $PATH_TO_KEYCHAIN`. But couldnt find a solution for the same in python anywhere. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a Python API for this. Use the `subprocess` module to call the external program.

```
import subprocess

cmd = "security unlock-keychain -p".split() 
cmd += [keychain_password, path_to_keychain]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

[Further reading on `subprocess`](http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/)